# Mysql query help. I need to make sure atleast one record is returning

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that I know it should atleast return one row. How can i modify my follow query to make sure that album returns data. thanks for any help.

Query Here. I know that Album has a row and I need to return it.

```
    select distinct p.*,
 a.ID as parentalbumid,a.CreatorID as albumcreatorid,a.AlbumName,a.AlbumDescription,a.AlbumDefaultImageURL,a.Private,a.DateCreated,a.AdultContent,a.PasswordProtected,a.AllowTags,a.TypeID,a.AlbumAutoID,
 mainuser.Username as mainuserusername,mainuser.ID as mainuserid,mainuser.PictureUrl as mainuserpictureurl,
c.ID as commentID,c.PhotoID as commentphotoid,c.OutputMessage,c.CommentDate,
t.ID as tagID,t.PhotoID as tagphotoid,t.UserID,t.TextTag,t.LeftLocation,t.TopLocation,
u.ID as userid,u.Username,u.FirstName,u.LastName,u.PictureUrl
from photos p
inner join albums a on a.ID = p.AlbumID
inner join users mainuser on mainuser.ID = p.UserID
left join comments c on c.PhotoID = p.ID
left join tags t on t.PhotoID = p.ID 
left join users u on u.ID = c.CommentBy
where a.AlbumAutoID = 3
order by p.DateUploaded desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only `LEFT JOIN`s (and put the table `albums` as the first table of your `FROM`):

```
select distinct p.*,
 a.ID as parentalbumid,a.CreatorID as albumcreatorid,a.AlbumName,a.AlbumDescription,a.AlbumDefaultImageURL,a.Private,a.DateCreated,a.AdultContent,a.PasswordProtected,a.AllowTags,a.TypeID,a.AlbumAutoID,
 mainuser.Username as mainuserusername,mainuser.ID as mainuserid,mainuser.PictureUrl as mainuserpictureurl,
c.ID as commentID,c.PhotoID as commentphotoid,c.OutputMessage,c.CommentDate,
t.ID as tagID,t.PhotoID as tagphotoid,t.UserID,t.TextTag,t.LeftLocation,t.TopLocation,
u.ID as userid,u.Username,u.FirstName,u.LastName,u.PictureUrl
from albums a
left join photos p on a.ID = p.AlbumID
left join users mainuser on mainuser.ID = p.UserID
left join comments c on c.PhotoID = p.ID
left join tags t on t.PhotoID = p.ID 
left join users u on u.ID = c.CommentBy
where a.AlbumAutoID = 3
order by p.DateUploaded desc;
```